# Single responsibility and methods

Tags: java, software-design, solid-principles, code-cleanup, clean-architecture

I think I might answer my own question here but lets say I understand the SRP on the method level to mean that a method serves one role. If I have methods that each individually cover one specific role in my class, but a method that uses lots of those methods to accomplish one role like a save() would everything still adhere to SRP?

Here is an example:

```
public void saveCertificationToDB(Cert cert){
  if(certificateIsNotExpired(cert){
      setCertProperties(cert);
      openConnectionToDB();
      overwriteCertificateInDB(cert);
      closeConnectionToDB();
      notifyUserSaveSuccessful();
      }
 }
```

Comment: That's mostly opinion-based; there is no hard-and-fast rule. However the 3 method calls with "DB" in them seem like they should be in their own method for which the method name `saveCertificationToDB` seems applicable. The method you show above could be called `validateAndSaveCertificationAndNotifyUser()` - although normally user notification would normally be in an entirely different layer of your application (but you could just have a more generic callback at this level) -- it all depends.

Answer (score 0):

Single Responsibility Principle:

There is no specific rule , just SRP is a guideline. But if you want to think for SRP then you should keep in mind always

> Single reason to change a code block like class, function etc.

But as per your given function, there are many reason to change your function code block.

Example:

if properties setting function modify for any reason then you have to be change your **saveCertificationToDB()**

And same way if any changes in other calling function for any other reason then also your **saveCertificationToDB()** need to change

so, Generally there are lot of lacks